# How to upload photo from iphone to facebook?

Tags: iphone, facebook, upload, photo

I want to upload photo form any iphone device to my facebook account. I want to create my own apps that works in any apple  device.Suggest header file in XCode.

Comment: What are your iOS targets as from iOS6 apple launch there own FB framework

Comment: Take a look on this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811799/post-image-on-facebook-using-3-1-sdk

Comment: @Niks welcome to stk dear come join in this rum  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat

Answer (score 0):

As there is iOS6 framework for Facebook.

And if you are using Facebook SDK, then below is the method for upload picture to FB Wall.

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:self.image
                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error) {
           if (!error) {
               if([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successPostPictureResponse:)])
                   [self.apiCallDelegate successPostPictureResponse:result];
           }
           else{
               if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPostPictureResponse:)])
                   [self.apiCallDelegate failedPostPictureResponse:error];
           }
    }];
```

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ios 6 then you can use default framework for Facebook. but if you want support for all device then you can use Facebook sdk from Facebook developer page. if any query then  you can ask me. in Facebook developer page you must create app for your application.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use  Sharekit 2.0 which supports all the features like: sharing files , sharing images , posting something on you wall.
You can integrate the sharekit 2.0 in your application : Link : https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit. I tried this and it worked for me.

Thanks